# c# wpf listBox selectionchanged is wrongfuly (for me) fired when removing an item from obseevable collection which was already selected when removed

Tags: c#, listbox, observablecollection, selectionchanged, outofrangeexception

hey guys i'v been trying to figure it out for 2 days and no luck.
i have an observableCollection that stores values and presents them in list box.
i want to check item int listbbox(lbBookDetails) and remove it from my collection(myBooks) using delete button.

after i press the delete buttton,
i get the element of chosen index,update data for a referenced object inside my chosen Book, and the remove it.

```
//get chosen book
Book newBook = myBooks.ElementAt(lbBookDetails.SelectedIndex);
//take one book dowfrom authors list
getAuthorByName(newBook.author.fullName()).numOfBooks--; 
//remove the book
myBooks.Remove(myBooks.ElementAt(lbBookDetails.SelectedIndex)); //<--- problem
```

this line sends an event to selectionChange for some reason,and when it searches for index it gets -1 and i have "Argumentoutofrange exception"

why so?

Comment: Presumably because you have no selected item. What is the code for `selectionChange()`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment and sorry for the delay
 this is the code for selectionChange()
I'll write it in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

Why is exception? becouse you remove item which is selected, when u remove selected item from observableCollection then send imformation to listBox that collections was changed and item which is seleted was removed so listbox change selected index on -1 and call event selectedchange.

Tips: in future u have problem with null reference in line

```
myBooks.Remove(myBooks.ElementAt(lbBookDetails.SelectedIndex)); //<--- problem
```

u this:

```
var index = lbBookDetails.SelectedIndex;
myBooks.Remove(myBooks.ElementAt(index ));
```

Sorry for my English

Comment: thanks haqu,
what are the advantages of this phrasing over the old one?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for selectionChange()

```
    private void lbBookDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var book = myBooks.ElementAt(lbBookDetails.SelectedIndex) as Book;
        if (book == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        tboAuthor.Text = book.author.fullName();      //displaying the values in case ArgumentOutOfRangeException selection from box
        tboCopies.Text = book.numOfCopys.ToString();
        tboPrice.Text = book.Price.ToString();
        tbonumByAuthor.Text = book.author.numOfBooks.ToString();

    }
```